# Smoother UI for “purge all comments” from the moderator dashboard

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface, moderator-tools, deleted-comments

From the moderator dashboard, using the “mod → purge all comments” tool refreshes the page. When there are many flagged posts and I'm processing a flag from the middle of the list, this makes it hard to locate the flag I was currently handling.

Please change the UI so that the “purge all comments” tool doesn't refresh the page, or otherwise arranges for the post I was looking at to be at the same scrolling position and still expanded.